# High-pass filter in Python (Scipy)

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, highpass-filter

This code is taken from a pitch detection algorithm. It is called before pitch detection to remove low-frequency noises.

```
def highpass_filter(y, sr):
  filter_stop_freq = 70  # Hz
  filter_pass_freq = 100  # Hz
  filter_order = 1001

  # High-pass filter
  nyquist_rate = sr / 2.
  desired = (0, 0, 1, 1)
  bands = (0, filter_stop_freq, filter_pass_freq, nyquist_rate)
  filter_coefs = signal.firls(filter_order, bands, desired, nyq=nyquist_rate)

  # Apply high-pass filter
  filtered_audio = signal.filtfilt(filter_coefs, [1], y)
  return filtered_audio
```

I have trouble understanding what the parameters `filter_stop_freq`, `filter_pass_freq` and `filter_order` mean. I have read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firls.html) but it did not help me.

Comment: "Design a digital FIR filter, of length 1001, where the gain at DC is 0 (silence), and all frequencies up to filter_stop_freq 70 Hz are also blocked, then the gain can rise up to filter_pass_freq 100 Hz, where the gain should be 1 (should be passed unchanged), and the gain from there up to the Nyquist frequency should stay flat at 1.  Then use this filter on the signal, with one forward-in-time pass and one backward-in-time pass."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters generally can't just have a single cut-off frequency (otherwise their complexity will be huge).  So a transition region is usually needed.

In this case, the `filter_stop_freq` is that frequency below which the filter MUST act like a stop filter and `filter_pass_freq` is that frequency above which the filter MUST act like a pass filter.

The frequencies between `filter_stop_freq` and `filter_pass_freq` are the [transition region or band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_band).

Because this is designing an FIR filter, `filter_order` is just the length (number of taps) of the filter. The higher the order, usually, the better the fit (and the smaller the transition region can be).